# Running balanced audio over CAT6?

Tags: cable, xlr

I have to run stereo, unbalanced line-level audio about 120 ft, past a lot of heavy noise sources. I will grab some DI boxes and run balanced audio instead.

My question is: I have a ton of 24 AWG shielded CAT6 (not CAT6a though) wiring available, and the components to wire it up to DI boxes. Can I use this instead of XLR? From what I can tell XLR is also 24 AWG so change in voltage drop characteristics won't be an issue.

If I can, how should I wire it? +/- for each channel on a twisted pair, and tie grounds together and to shield?

Comment: Although this is not the right SE site to ask because your question is not about designing sound but about home audio, I think your plan will work with the wiring scheme you propose.

Comment: @EMV Thanks. And sorry about that. I usually post home audio questions at audiokarma, but this time I thought I'd see if SE had a site. First visit here, wasn't quite sure what good topics were!

Comment: @JasonC - no worries, we still need to get our On-Topic page cleaned up to make the distinction more clear.

Comment: @AJHenderson It's a little unclear too if new users look at existing questions for topic reference (e.g. http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26488/cat5-utp-for-audio?rq=1, which I guess this is sort of a duplicate of anyways). :) Good luck with the site! It seems like a good one (and congrats on your new mod-ship)!

Comment: @JasonC - yeah, some of the old migrated stuff is a little bit questionable in relation to the new scope.  In the case of a PA, I suppose it would actually be on topic.